# VHDL - Inferred Latch With Reset - FSM

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fsm

I have an issue with this process where if I include a reset statement, I get an inferred latch. However, if I do not include the reset statement, I do not get an inferred latch on duty_cycle_triangle.

```
    SIGNAL duty_cycle_triangle : INTEGER := 0;
    SIGNAL count_up : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL tick_zero : STD_LOGIC;

    triangle_count: PROCESS(clk, reset signal, tick_zero)
        BEGIN
            IF (reset = '1') THEN
                duty_cycle_triangle <= 0;
            ELSIF (RISING_EDGE(clk)) THEN
                IF (tick_zero = '1') THEN
                    IF (count_up = '1') THEN
                        duty_cycle_triangle <= duty_cycle_triangle + 2;
                    ELSE
                        duty_cycle_triangle <= duty_cycle_triangle - 2;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS;
```

I am trying to design an FSM that will output a triangle wave using a PWM and an FSM shown below:

```
        FSM_comb: PROCESS(currentState, duty_cycle_triangle)
        BEGIN
            CASE currentState IS
                WHEN triangle_up =>
                    PWM_enable <= '1';
                    count_up <= '1';
                    IF (duty_cycle_triangle > 99) THEN
                        nextState <= triangle_down;
                    ELSE
                        nextState <= triangle_up;
                    END IF;
                WHEN triangle_down =>
                    PWM_enable <= '1';
                    count_up <= '0';
                    IF (duty_cycle_triangle < 1) THEN
                        nextState <= triangle_up;
                    ELSE
                        nextState <= triangle_down;
                    END IF;
            END CASE;
    END PROCESS;


    FSM_seq: PROCESS(clk, reset)
        BEGIN
            IF (reset = '1') THEN
                currentState <= triangle_up;
            ELSIF (RISING_EDGE(clk)) THEN
                currentState <= nextState;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS FSM_seq;
```

Basically, after every "tick" I want the duty cycle of the triangle wave to increase by 2. After the duty cycle reaches 100, I want the duty cycle to decrease by 2 until the duty cycle reaches 0. Once the duty cycle reaches 0, I want the duty cycle to start increasing from 0 again until it reaches 100 and it starts over.

Does anyone see any problems with my code or can anyone point me in the right direction to correcting any issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a sequential process, only include a reset and a clock in your sensitivity list. I suspect that it's inferring the latch because you're including too many signals in this process:

`triangle_count: PROCESS(clk, reset signal, tick_zero)`

It should just be

`triangle_count: PROCESS(reset, clk)`

The tools don't see that as a sequential process and make it combinational and that's how you get your latch.

Comment: Synthesis attention to sensitivity lists historically comes from requiring post synthesis simulation behavior matches input behavior, now verified through formal methods instead. With or without the latches the simulation and synthesized models behavior would match. Mapping behavior to synthesis primitives which should depend on inherent priority does not depend on sensitivity lists. That there are latches is a particular synthesis tool mapping defect and not a problem with the process statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it out i'm wondering if when the reset statement is removed, the tool is recognising the process as a synchronous process and inferring registers. In this case you don't need to explicitly define duty_cycle_triangle for each outcome of the process as the value is stored in a register.

With the reset statement included it may be treating the process as combinatorial and therefore inferring latches to store the state of duty_cycle_triangle when it's not explicitly defined.

Either way I agree with Russell's suggestion of changing the process sensitivity list which should get rid of the latch.